# Сделала(,) как велено

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужна ли запятая?
**Сделала, как велено.**

Comment: А каково решение Автора вопроса?

Comment: Автор предложения поставил запятую, но возникли сомнения.

Answer (score 3):

Поначалу кажется, что предложение очень похоже на [цельное по смыслу выражение](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm):
***сделать как следует*** (как полагается, как подобает), ***выполнить как должно*** (как надо, как нужно).

Нашлось в словаре Ефремовой:
[**ве́лено**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/145467/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE), *предик. разг.*
О чьём-либо приказании, распоряжении кому-либо сделать что-либо.

Сделала, как велено = сделала [так], как [велели](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) (как было велено, как кто-то велел).
Думаю, что запятая нужна.

Если же не сделает, как велено, «браты» прикинут его шубой или матрацем. [Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)]
Егор вертелся, как велено, с тоской думая, что время уходит понапрасну. [Борис Васильев. Не стреляйте в белых лебедей (1973)]
Все сделали, как велено. И артиста нашли похожего. [Игорь Мартынов, Петр Каменченко. Шоу бродячее // «Столица», 1997.10.28]
― Ну, так так и делай, как велено! [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)]

Answer (score 2):

— Ты выполнила то, о чем я просил?
— Сделала, как велено.(и сделала, и уточнение про то как )

— Как вы меня постригли?
— Сделала как велено.
— Я не просил так стричь.

Comment: Ну что ж, вы делаете успехи, Jim Korbett, я отдаю голос за ваш ответ, примеры получилсь убедительными. Вы неплохо смотритесь: настаиваете на своем мнении, если считаете  его верным, но можете изменить его в соответствии с новой информацией. Я считаю такую гибкость мышления достоинством личности, хотя некоторые полагают, что это бесприципность (по мне же такая приципиальность   -  никому не нужный консерватизм и закрытость от всего нового). Так что у вас есть потенциальная возможность стать "звездой форума", хотя пока еще рано делать прогнозы.

Comment: Можно еще определить грамматику в этих вариантах, иначе ответ не будет полным. Мы выбираем между сложноподчиненным предложением "сделала так, как велено" с пропущенным указательным словом и устойчивым оборотом "как велено", который в позиции обстоятельства не обособляется.

Comment: Спасибо за лесные слова, но я не разбирался в этой теме еще позавчера, а разобрался только после не совсем правильного ответа на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я как раз об этом и говорю. У вас хорошая обучаемость и неплохое чувство языка, так как вы привели очень хорошие примеры. Честно говоря, я не рассчитывала на такой эффект.  Знание - дело наживное, а научить всегда легче, чем переучить. Люди, которые уже имеют какие-то знания, часто не хотят  их менять  и совершенствовать.